# Saving Custom Data to Order Item

Tags: attributes, orders, sales-order

I want to create an attribute just like weight for each product, called extraInfo and update that info in the sales order.  I don't want this data being saved to each product of the same type just that specific item going into the order.

Comment: This is something I actually do quite a bit. A couple of questions. Which version of Magento are you on? When do you want to attach the data to the item? At the time it is added to the cart or at the time the order is completed?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are product options. Product options are used by Magento to store details about the product being purchased. They are then serialized and stored in the database. On an order item (instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`), you can set them with `$orderItem->setProductOptions()`.

A potential pitfall of product options is the complexity that they introduce, and sometimes, you'd be better off to use a configurable product. However, since you don't want the data saved to the product, but instead to the item on the order, product options are your best bet.